# Using Ubuntu on a windows PC

Tags: windows-10

Should I use virtual box to run Ubuntu on my windows PC or download Ubuntu software available on windows Store

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to do. In its current form, this question may generate speculative answers.

Comment: Judge for yourself - try both and see which you prefer.